# How to deploy dependent contracts on MainNet using geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment

Suppose I have a contract A that depends on a contract B and an interface I.

```
contract B {
 ...
}

interface I {
 ...
}

contract A is B {
  I objectSample;
  ...
}
```

On a standard deployment where A is not dependent on any other contract, interface or library, I'd do something like this:

```
var contractA_Model = eth.contract(contractA_ABI)
var contractA_DeployTx = {from: eth.coinbase, data: contractA_Bytecode, gas: ...}
var contractA_Deploy = contractA_Model.new(..., contractA_DeployTx)
```

On the scenario I mentioned above, what would I have to do to deploy an instance of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scenario you need to compile contracts, then deploy `A` contract. `B` contract and `I` interface will be included in bytecode of `A`